# Setup for Lax Milgram theorem

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Evans - first edition - chapter 6 - exercise 1

[Or second edition - chapter 6 - exercise 2]

I have to show that $Lu= -\sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij}(x)u_{x_i})_{x_j} + c(x)uv$ satisfies the hypothesis of the Lax Milgram theorem.

So we have the bilinear form:
$$|B[u,v]| =\left|\int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij}(x)u_{x_i}v_{x_j} + c(x)u(x)v(x) dx\right|\leq\int_U  \sum_{i,j=1}^n \left|  a^{ij}(x)u_{x_i}v_{x_j}\right| + \left|c(x)u(x)v(x) \right|dx$$
$$\leq  \|a^{ij}(x)\|_{L^\infty(U)}\int_U  \sum_{i,j=1}^n  \left|u_{x_i}v_{x_j}\right|dx + \int_U\left|c(x)u(x)v(x) \right| dx$$
Holders
$$\leq  \|a^{ij}(x)\|_{L^\infty(U)}\int_U  \sum_{i,j=1}^n  \left|u_{x_i}v_{x_j}\right|dx + \|c(x)\|_{L^\infty(U)}\|u\|_{L^2(U)}\|v\|_{L^2(U)}$$

How do I get this less than $\alpha\|u\|_{H_0^1(U)}\|v\|_{H_0^1(U)}$ for some $\alpha >0$?

Seems like I just want the terms on left to die somehow, and then let $\alpha = \|c(x)\|_{L^{\infty}(U)}$ (but even then, $\alpha =0$ isn't impossible).

Comment: Note that if $u \in H_0^1(U)$, then $\| u\|_{L^2(U)} \leq \| u\|_{H^1_0(U)}$. For the integral in the first summand, you can again use Hölder.

Comment: You really should try to solve the problem yourself. So I assume that you don't know how to handle the integral in the first summand?! Let's rewrite it: $\int_{U} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n \lvert u_{x_i} v_{x_j}\rvert \, \text{d} x = \sum_{i, j = 1}^n\int_{U}  \lvert u_{x_i} \rvert \cdot \lvert v_{x_j} \rvert \, \text{d}x \leq \sum_{i, j = 1}^n \Big(\int_U \lvert u_{x_i} \rvert^2 \Big)^{1/2} \Big(\int_U \lvert v_{x_j} \rvert^2 \Big)^{1/2}$. Now, for each $i \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$ we have that $\lvert u_{x_i}\rvert \leq \|D u\|_{\ell^2}$. (In fact, *any* norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ works.)

Comment: @Mike I wasn't thinking to use Poincare inequality before. Thanks very much.